# More secure way to configure Centos/Apache for Multiple Users

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, apache-http-server

I have a public Linux server running CentOS, Apache/PHP/MySQL. This server currently hosts multiple WordPress Blogs and Websites I am developing.

Currently, I have "userdir" enabled, and set up virtualhosts for each website. Under each user directory there is a *htdocs* file which is the root directory for each website.

- Apache needs the necessary read/write permissions to the web files
- The user needs to be able to read/write so I can upload the files from my IDE

For the permissions, I add the user "apache" to the user group. For example if I have a user called 'mark', I will run *"usermod -a -G mark,apache apache"*, and then do *"chmod -R 770 /home/mark/htdocs"* to give Apache access to the web files. The problem with this is that Apache can read/write/execute on everything. I suppose this is bad for security because Apache should only be able to write and execute directories it needs to.

**My question is, what is the optimal way to configure the server so:**

- **Apache can read all files in the web root and write to directories it needs to (for uploads etc...)**
- **The user account can have full control so that I can upload/modify files as I develop the websites**

Comment: Does this help at all? http://superuser.com/questions/695162/how-to-chown-directory-for-multiple-users Its a semi different question, but the answer should help.

Comment: `For the permissions, I add the user "apache" to the user group.`. Uhm. Apache has its own group so that if (or rather, **when** if you use an Internet facing website) it gets comprimised it can do little harm. If you add it to users you just disabled that security. (hint: leave it to its own user group our to user 'none'). You already seem aware that this is not *the right way*, but repeating that fact will do no harm.

Comment: Interesting reading: 

[http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9748/security-implications-of-having-files-owned-by-the-apache-user](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9748/security-implications-of-having-files-owned-by-the-apache-user)

and 

[http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37433/how-to-set-secure-permissions-for-multiple-users-and-multiple-websites](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37433/how-to-set-secure-permissions-for-multiple-users-and-multiple-websites)