# umask blocks either Plex or Nextcloud access to external fat32 HDD

Tags: linux, permissions, external-hard-drive, mount, umask

Trying to make my superPi (with Plex, Nextcloud, VPN), I have a permissions problem on my external HDD:

I have attached an external HDD to my Raspberry Pi, that holds all my media (photos, homevideos, our CD-rips, etc). I want both Nextcloud and Plex to have access, but I don't seem to get this combination working.

Following [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/695186) I created the group *mediausers* and added the users *plex* and *www-data*:

```
sudo groupadd mediausers
sudo usermod -a -G mediausers plex
sudo usermod -a -G mediausers www-data
```

The drive was (already before connecting it to my Pi) formated as vfat (or so it appears on the Pi). With the following line on /etc/fstab I mounted the drive (partly based on [this post](https://help.nextcloud.com/t/you-dont-have-permissions-to-upload-or-create-files-here-local-external-ntfs-3g-storage/5420/4) on the Nextcloud forum) with mediausers as the group:

```
UUID=1B1C-14D8  /CloudMEDIA/    vfat    nofail,uid=pi,gid=mediausers,umask=003         0       0
```

Without umask Plex happily serves my pictures but I get a 'you don't have permission to create or upload in this folder'-error in Nextcloud. With the umask Nextcloud is happy and allows me to do what I want, but Plex doesn't serve any media anymore ('Unavailable; please check the necessary drive is mounted').

How can I make both Plex, Nextcloud and myself happy? How do I get file/mount permisssions right? Any help much appreciated!

---

Nextcloud version: 11.0.3 (stable)
Plex Media Server Version: 3.5.0
Operating system: Raspbian Jessie
Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian)
PHP version: 7.0.16

Comment: The problem may be because the disk isn't in a native Unix/Linux file system. VFat doesn't support Unix permissions...